# How to graph a mathematical function for "Distance and Speed over Time" in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I'm struggling with some Python homework.

I'm really new to Python, and coding in general. I have really basic knowledge in Python, and somewhat acceptable level in JavaScript.

My issue: I have to make a graph to represent these two functions:

```
distance = (x**2/2 - np.cos(5*x) - 7)

speed = (x + 5*np.sin(5*x))
```

Between the timestamps 3 and 6 (inclusive)

I know I have to use Pandas to make a DataFrame, I know I have to use MatPlotLib to make the actual plot, and I have to use Numpy for the math to work, but I can't get the math to be recognised as mathematical functions because I simply don't know how.

This is what the graph should look like:
[Graph for Distance and Speed over Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEuuk.png)

This is what my code looks for now:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 10

time = [3, 6]

distance = (x**2/2 - np.cos(5*x) - 7)

speed = (x + 5*np.sin(5*x))

values = {'Distance': distance, 'Speed': speed, 'Time': time}

df = pd.DataFrame(data= values)

df.plot(title='Distance and speed', xlabel='Time (hours)', ylabel='Distance (km) / Speed (km/h)', x='Time')

plt.show()
```

x = 10 I know shouldn't be included, but since I'm missing the part that makes the math work, I have to include it to make it "work" and not get an error.

I have a vague idea that using Numpy is the answer to my problem, but I don't know how (for now, hopefully).

How wrong am I? Can anyone help me?

Comment: "I have a vague idea that using Numpy is the answer"?  It depends on where you are in your Python course.  Is the present assignment on Python basics or Numpy and Pandas?  If it is on basic Python you can use basic Python for loops to create data and matplotlib to display.  If it is about NumPy, you can use NumPy array operations to create data.  Since you are new to Python, I would be surprised if you are required to use Pandas for one of your first data generation and plotting assignments.

Comment: It's my second assignment. We had classes on Numpy and Pandas, and we made a DataFrame on the previous lesson. We had 5 classes total, and it is assumed that the student only knows how to use a PC but has no prior programming knowledge. It's getting harder to keep up, honestly.

Comment: I posted an answer using Numpy and Pandas.  If it's getting harder to keep up it could be this class did not spend enough time with basic Python programming and building on that.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections to posted version

- Use variable t for time (rather than x)
- np.arange(3, 6.01, 0.01) to get time from 3 to 6 inclusive

**Code**

```
# time values from 3 to 6 inclusive in steps of 0.01 (use 6.01 to include 6)
t = np.arange(3, 6.01, 0.01)  # t for time

# Use NumPy array operations to compute distance and speed at all time values (i.e. x axis)
distance = (t**2/2 - np.cos(5*t) - 7)
speed = (t + 5*np.sin(5*t))
values = {'Distance': distance, 'Speed': speed, 'Time': t}  # x is time t

df = pd.DataFrame(data= values)
df.plot(title='Distance and speed', xlabel='Time (hours)', ylabel='Distance (km) / Speed (km/h)', x='Time')

plt.show()
```

[image]